# Hide and Show based on Code in code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I want to hide and show based on the code written in CodeBehind file.
The Code is as follows:

```
 <div class="actions">
    <div class="prebidConfirm">
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="ConfirmLinkButton" OnClick="ConfirmLinkButton_Click" 
                                           CssClass="button-go" Text="<%$ Resources: General, Yes %>">
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    <div class="prebidCancel">
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="CancelLinkButton" 
                                            Text="<%$ Resources: General, No %>">
                            </asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    <div class="prebidCancel">
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="OKButton" 
                                                Text="<%$ Resources: General, OK%>">
                                </asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And The code behind code is as follows:

```
private void SetLocalizedBodyText() {
            if (true){
                ConfirmLinkButton.Visible = false;
                CancelLinkButton.Visible = false;
                OKButton.Visible=true
            }
        }
```

But I am getting an error as 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_events' of null"

Comment: What's the point of the `if(true)` line? Also, might be easier to place those controls inside of an `<asp:Placeholder />` control and hide/show that instead. Where is the line where `_events` is being read?

Comment: if(true) is some condition based on that It should be Hide and Show and and What is next one i dint get you as I am new to Web form .net